# Hoptoad on rails test works but I don't get notified about exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hoptoad

I set up hoptoad on my prod server and ran rake hoptoad:test.  I get the notifier in my hoptoad interface so it seems to work great.  But then I forgot to migrate my database after my last deploy so I got a "ActionView::TemplateError" in my production log.  This caused a 500 so I feel like HopToad should have notified me about this.  Have any hoptoad users out there had this issue?

As a side note, is it standard practice to have your deploy process automatically migrate your production database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> As a side note, is it standard
>   practice to have your deploy process
>   automatically migrate your production
>   database?

The choice belongs to you. It's a standard practice to use Capistrano for deploying Rails apps. With capistrano you can run

```
cap deploy # to deploy the app
cap deploy:migrate # to migrate the app
cap deploy:migrations # to deploy and migrate at the same time
```

You can decide whether to execute the commands separately or not.

About hoptoad, I'm sorry but I don't have a Rails app with hoptoad installed to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any exception notification or logging plugins installed before hoptoad?  If so, make sure you remove them.  I had minor issues setting up hoptoad because of this interference.

Make sure your production server is set to the RAILS_ENV "production".  Development doesn't trigger hoptoad.

Comment: i have not installed any prior notification system.  ...im not really sure what you mean "set my production server", but i know my production application speaks to my production database if that's what you mean

Comment: ensure that the environment in which your rails application is running is "production".  When you got the ActiveView:TemplateError did it show you a debug screen or did it say "We're sorry but something went wrong".  If you got the debug screen, you need to change the RAILS_ENV